# how can i make a Google Internal Site Search Script by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

how can i make a Google Internal Site Search Script by JavaScript

Comment: i want the visitor of my site to search from Google  through a bar in my web site

Comment: You mean you want a bar on your website, which searches your website using google? Your description is unclear.

Comment: aularon's solution is not a good one. There is no reason to use javascript in this situation, and the submit button does not function as expected. Use my solution instead.

Comment: @Maged, @Eric's answer is more generic, it deals with cases where there's no javascript, beside it's simpler and cleaner. My answer was just to show how to use javascript to achieve that, but if you wanna use it on a site, I go for @Eric's method for sure.

Comment: Indeed. Technically, yours _does_ do a better job of answering the question, but it isn't the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/qEmhJ/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="q" />
<input type="button" value="search!" onclick="gsearch();" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function gsearch() {
    var q=document.getElementById('q').value;
    q+=' site:example.com';
    window.open('http://www.google.com/search?q='+encodeURIComponent(q));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't. Just use the standard form handling:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="yoursitehere.com"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Google Search" />
</form>
```

That's it. No javascript required.

http://jsfiddle.net/dWrsZ/

If you want it to open in a new window:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search" target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="yoursitehere.com"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Google Search" />
</form>
```